# Purrr Implementation of For-Loop

Tags: r, for-loop, tidyverse, purrr

I am trying to develop a logistic regression model in R. I am trying to loop over rows of a data frame (or tibble) so that I can multiply a subset of the columns in that row by another vector as a dot product.

I initially tried to accomplish some preparatory work using purrr's vector functions, but was having difficulty and decided to implement it in a for-loop.

This is the working design I have with a For-Loop:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Define necessary functions
 lambdaFunc <- function(factors,theta){
 return((1+exp(sum(factors*theta)))^(-1))
}

# y is 0 or 1
# x and theta are a numeric vectors
indiv_likhd <- function(y,x,theta){
 return(lambdaFunc(x,theta)^y*(1-lambdaFunc(x,theta))^(1-y))
}

# Assuming df is dataframe of the form
# Col1                Col2      ...     ColN
# isDefault(0 or 1)   factor1   ...     factorN
likhds <- function(df,theta){
 df <- as.data.frame(df)
 likhds <- vector("numeric",nrow(df))
 for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
   likhds[i] <- indiv_likhd(df[i,1],df[i,2:ncol(df)],theta)
 }
 return(likhds)
}
```

So

```r
testdf <- tibble(y=c(1,0),x_1=c(1,1),x_2=c(1,1),x_3=c(1,1))
testTheta <- c(1,1,1)
likhds(testdf,testTheta)
```

yields

```r
[1] 0.04742587 0.95257413
```

Is there a way to implement this with vector functions-specifically the purr package? This is my first real question on stackoverflow so I apologize if there is something missing or unclear, in which case, please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without changing your `lambdaFunc` and `indiv_likhd` we could rewrite your `for` loop with `pmap`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

testdf %>%
   mutate(new_col = pmap_dbl(., ~indiv_likhd(c(...)[1], c(...)[-1], testTheta)))

#      y   x_1   x_2   x_3 new_col
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#1     1     1     1     1  0.0474
#2     0     1     1     1  0.953
```

`c(...)` is used to capture all the values passed to `pmap` (here the entire row), so `c(...)[1]` means the first value in the row, `c(...)[-1]` means everything other than the first values in the row.

Comment: Very elegant! This is what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option

```
f <- function(df, theta) {
    df %>%
        group_by(y) %>%
        nest() %>%
        mutate(likhds = map2_dbl(y, data, function(y, x) indiv_likhd(y, x, theta))) %>%
        pull(likhds)
}
f(testdf, testTheta)
#[1] 0.04742587 0.95257413
```

Explanation: We `nest` data by `y`, then use `map2_dbl` to loop through the pairs of `y` and `data` (which are your `x` values) for every row, and return the output of `indiv_likhd` as a `double` vector.